# Computing mid in Interpolation Search?

Tags: algorithm, search

I came to know that **Interpolation Search** is a modification of **Binary Search** where in binary search the input is divided into two equal halves in each iteration by computing

```
mid = (low + high) / 2
```

and in Interpolation search the mid is computed as

```
mid = low + (key - arr[low]) * ((high - low) / (arr[high] - arr[low]))
```

Now I need to understand this formula of calculating `mid` in interpolation search.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search#Sample_implementation

Comment: Assume `low = 10`, `high = 20`, `arr[low] == 100` and `arr[high] == 200`. Now calculate `mid` for `key == 110`, `key == 150`, and `key == 190`.

Comment: @Henrik but how is this formula derived?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can think of array `arr` as a function `f` that acts on index and return a value, which is monotone (because array is sorted). So you have your initial data `f(low) = m` and `f(high) = M`. Now you can interpolate your function `f` with a straight line, which is quite reasonable to do because your `f` is monotone and you have only 2 points.
So your interpolation should be line (linear function) that pass throw points `(low, m)` and `(high, M)`. This is it's equation

```
(y - f(low))/(f(high) - f(low)) = (x - low)/(high - low)
```

So `y` here is the element of search space and `x` is from domain (x is index of array). So if your function `f` would be the same as it's interpolation, then index of your `key` would be:

```
x = low + (high - low)*(key - f(low))/(f(high) - f(low))
```

So, assuming that your function `f` is close to it's interpolation, you should just check the value `f` at `x` to see if it is the goal. Otherwise you just shrink your interpolation interval.

Comment: how to get this formula - http://formulas.tutorvista.com/math/interpolation-formula.html

Answer (score 9):

An extention to *@JustAnotherCurious* answer

the equation perposed by him was based on [Interpolation Formula](http://formulas.tutorvista.com/math/interpolation-formula.html) (equ of a line)

> [image]

Now, think`f()` as function that takes an index and return its `y` axis value,

```
y1 = f(low)
y2 = f(high)
x1 = low
x2 = high

(y - f(low)) = [(f(high) - f(low)) / (high - low)] * (x - low);

OR

x = low + [(high - low) * (y - f(low))] / (f(high) - f(low))

here: y = key
we are looking for position(value) of x.
```